# I want my wordpress post to load a few at a time on user scroll similar to facebook

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want my wordpress post to load a few at a time on user scroll similar to facebook, for example my web page should load 10 automatically and when I get the bottom of the page I want it to load 10 more until all posts are loaded on the home page.

How would I go about doing this? I have done some digging around but I'm pretty new to wordpress and have not been able to find a script or plug in that could accomplish the task. All help is greatly appreciated!

My website is [dev.vercitycolab.com](http://dev.vercitycolab.com) (it's only loading 10 right now because when I posted all of my video posts up it was loading WAY too slow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of coding it yourself, here is a plugin that does what you are asking for: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/infinite-scroll/